# Openlayers add custom div above map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm newbe here. I have map (OSM) with openlayers. I tryed to add measure  tools. I'm using this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/measure.html But i need to move buttons on the map like scaleline.

I've tryed this code

```
document.getElementById("map").innerHTML += '<div id="options" style="position: absolute;z-index: 10000;bottom: 0px;left: 100px;"><input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" /><label for="noneToggle"> Nav</label><input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" /><label for="lineToggle"> measure </label>  <span id="output"></span></div>'
```

But it make map freeze.
Page with map looks like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/map/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

So i can't just add my buttons in #map. 
So how could I add custom div on map via js?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i should used `document.createElement("div")` instead `innerHTML`